# Link stylesheet preload vs W3C validation

Tags: css, w3c-validation, preload, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to satisfy 2 checkers: [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and [google page insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights)

**Google Page Insight** suggested to me to load asynchronously all blocking CSS files. Well, I've rewritten the stylesheet file inclusion in preload way, as follow,  and deferred from head to the end of the body:

```
 ...
    <link rel="preload" href="mystyles.css" media="all" as="style" 
                     onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>
</body>
```

Google Page Insight forced me to get it out from the head and put it at the end of the body.

Ok, I'm OK against Google Page Insight.

But **W3C Validator** says me now:

> Error: A link element must not appear as a descendant of a body element unless the link element has an itemprop attribute or has a rel attribute whose value contains dns-prefetch, pingback, preconnect, prefetch, prerender, or stylesheet

Why "preload" is not admitted in rel attribute out of the head? I've tried to assign an itemprop, but it's not possible to have an itemprop and a rel in the same link.

Comment: Link preload is a draft and is a working in progress. W3 validator is based on the current standards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. A checker bug was caused this. When [I added `rel=preload`support to the checker](https://github.com/validator/validator/commit/d6390af720e25c9cb4a6f074ef7aa8f877f5df90), I forgot to add it to the list of the `rel` values the checker code compares against to decide if a particular `link` element is allowed in the body.

[I’ve now fixed it in the checker sources](https://github.com/validator/validator/commit/783641b3cc3609937c9c6abdf801cc73aad29cad) and pushed the fix to https://validator.w3.org/nu/.

So, the checker will no longer report an error for the code above. Thanks for catching this.

Answer (score 0):

I use an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea return success.

look in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Comment: how you can read in accepted answer, W3C maintainer fixed the validator a long ago.